# Dismiss and Pop a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I want to go back two levels on my view controller stack. I have three segues in this order: Show, Show, Present Modally. There is a navigation controller in use. From my 4th view I want to go back to the 2nd view. I have tried using
    `self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false);`

and

`self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);`

The second one works only if the 2nd and 3rd segues as 'Present Modally'. How can I get them to work with a dismiss and a pop?

Comment: Seems like you'd have to dismiss the presented view controller before popping the other two.

Comment: You could use an unwind segue instead.

Comment: @rdelmar You could only use an unwind segue if you're using a storyboard, right?

Comment: @LyndseyScott, yes that's true.

Answer (score 5):

Try dismissing the presented view controller before popping the other two:

```
func dismissThenDoublePop() {

    // Get the presenting/previous view
    let previousView = self.presentingViewController as UINavigationController

    // Dismiss the current view controller then pop the others
    // upon completion
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:  {

        // Get an array of the current view controllers on your nav stack
        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = previousView.viewControllers as [UIViewController];

        // Then either pop two view controllers, i.e. pop
        // to viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2], or
        // pop to the second view controller in the nav stack,
        // i.e. viewControllers[1]. (In this case I've used the
        // first option.)
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2], animated: true);

    });
}
```

Comment: It gets to the line that starts with `let viewControllers:...` and crashes with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @Ricca Yep, you're right navigation controller is nil in the presented view controller. Looking into an alternative now.

Comment: @Ricca OK, I've updated my answer to get the previous view as a UINavigationController before the dismissView block. I've tested this code and it works for me.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I Tried in this way to move to the home screen. Could you please check whether it is correct or not?  let previousView = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:  {
            
            // Get an array of the current view controllers on your nav stack
            let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = previousView.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
            
            previousView.popToViewController(viewControllers[0], animated: true);
            
        });

Answer (score 3):

You can use this technique

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/1153100

Simple and clean(Unwind segues)

```
@IBAction func unwindAction(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You use like this one.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just call *dismissViewControllerAnimated*.It will automatically dismiss all view controllers including presented model viewcontroller.

Objective - C

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Swift

```
self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
```